# AMPScript Lookup() with multiple criteria

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Haven't been able to dig up any mentions of this anywhere, but is there a way to use multiple criteria when using the `lookup()` AMPScript function?

Example:

`%%=lookup(DE_name,ValueColumn,language,"FR",country,"CA")=%%`

In this case, it would return the value from the desired column where language and country columns are equal to `FR` and `CA` respectively.

Comment: As @Jerry said... Yes you can. Below is documentation for any other questions you may have. http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#Lookup

Answer (score 3):

Probably should have just tried this out before posting, but just tested the above.

Looks like you can continue to add criteria pairs to lookup() and it seems to pull back records correctly.